# replace sub string in javascript string

Tags: javascript, jquery, string, replace

I have a string in Javascript,

`'WorkExperience_0_companydetails_0_name'`

I want to get the following string

`'WorkExperience_1_companydetails_1_name'`

How could I achieve this in jQuery?

Comment: Are all your strings like that ? Since below you said that you want the last index

Comment: why do you need jquery?

Comment: You can archive with `String.prototype.replace()`. [Check the document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace). but I think you want to change some specific problem such as updating element id or class name.

Comment: Antti, do you mean that you want to get the last index of an element in jQuery and then create a new element based on its index?

Comment: Something like... 'WorkExperience_1_companydetails_' + $controlList.eq(-1).index() + '_name'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**as you want to update its value by 1**

```
var str="WorkExperience_0_companydetails_0_name";

var ar = str.split("_");

var n=parseInt(ar[1],10)+1;
var newStr = str.replace(ar[1],n);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try,

```
"WorkExperience_0_companydetails_0_name".split("0").join('1');
```

Or

```
"WorkExperience_0_companydetails_0_name".replace("0","1");
```

### [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/laraprabhu/FW8Yj/)

Comment: I want to get the last index from the string first then add 1 to it then I need to update.

Comment: @faisalnasir i cant get you.. please explain again.. sorry.

Comment: "WorkExperience_0_companydetails_0_name" First I want to get the current index from the string i.e. "0" then I want to increment this index i.e. 0 +1 = 1 then I want to replace this index in the current string.

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<div class="test"></div>
<li id="foo1">foo</li>
<li id="bar1" class="test">bar</li>
<li id="baz1">baz</li>
<div class="test"></div>
</ul>
<div id="last"></div>



var foo = $( "li" );
// This implicitly calls .first()
console.log( "Index: " + foo.index( "li" ) ); // 0
console.log( "Index: " + foo.first().index( "li" ) ); // 0
var baz = $( "#baz1" );
console.log( "Index: " + baz.index( "li" )); // 2
var listItem = $( "#bar1" );
console.log( "Index: " + listItem.index( ".test" ) ); // 1
var div = $( "#last" );
console.log( "Index: " + div.index( "div" ) ); // 2`enter code here`
```